# Problem publishing Report that uses a separate On prem dataset via PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powerbi, powerbi-datasource, powerbi-api

My goal is to set up an Azure DevOps pipeline that can publish a report to the Development workspace.

The below code uses a service principle account to authenticate and then successfully publishes my test .pbix file (LocalReportModel.pbix") this file is a simple report and model structure

```
Import-Module MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt

$clientId = "****"
$clientSecret = "****"
$tenantId = "****"

$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $clientSecret -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($clientId, $secpasswd)

Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount -ServicePrincipal -Credential $credential -TenantId $tenantId
$workspaceName = "Development"
$workspace = Get-PowerBIWorkspace -Name $workspaceName
$file = "C:\Tasks\BI\LocalReportModel.pbix"

New-PowerBIReport -Path $file -Workspace $workspace -ConflictAction CreateOrOverwrite
```

We use On Premises Gateways so our model/dataset it not stored within the .pbix file
When I try the above with the file ReportOnly.pbix I get the error

New-PowerBIReport: Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest'

How can I add the link to the dataset currently within the workspace so that it will publish?

Thank you for any help you can offer.

I am trying to add a connection to the current dataset within my workspace and then publish my report (without a dataset) - The solution must be automated with no interaction

Detailed error after running Resolve-PowerBIError -Last

```
RequestId        : b61fca07-257c-4b72-831c-720f663781f0
Response         : Bad Request (400): {"error":{"code":"PowerBIModelNotFoundException","pbi.error":{"code":"PowerBIMode
                   lNotFoundException","parameters":{},"details":[],"exceptionCulprit":1}}}
PowerBIErrorInfo : PowerBIModelNotFoundException
ResponseDate     : Tue, 06 Jun 2023 12:57:49 GMT
RequestMethod    : POST
RequestUri       : https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/ac77d540-4689-4c0a-be9a-afa7a77he6aa/imports?datasetDispla
                   yName=Sales Margin Model.pbix&nameConflict=CreateOrOverwrite
InvocationInfo   : {New-PowerBIReport}
Line             : New-PowerBIReport -Path $file -Workspace $workspace -ConflictAction CreateOrOverwrite
Position         : At line:1 char:1
                   + New-PowerBIReport -Path $file -Workspace $workspace -ConflictAction C …
                   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
StackTrace       :    at Microsoft.PowerBI.Api.V2.Imports.UploadFile(String groupId, Stream file, String
                   datasetDisplayName, String nameConflict, Nullable`1 skipReport, Dictionary`2 customHeaders,
                   CancellationToken cancellationToken)
                      at Microsoft.PowerBI.Api.V2.Imports.PostImportFileWithHttpMessage(String groupId, Stream file,
                   String datasetDisplayName, String nameConflict, Nullable`1 skipReport, Dictionary`2 customHeaders,
                   CancellationToken cancellationToken)
                      at Microsoft.PowerBI.Api.V2.ImportsExtensions.PostImportWithFileInGroup(IImports operations,
                   String groupId, Stream fileStream, String datasetDisplayName, String nameConflict, Nullable`1
                   skipReport)
                      at Microsoft.PowerBI.Common.Api.Reports.ReportsClient.PostImportForWorkspace(Guid workspaceId,
                   String datasetDisplayName, String filePath, ImportConflictHandlerModeEnum nameConflict)
                      at Microsoft.PowerBI.Common.Api.Reports.ReportsClient.PostReportForWorkspace(Guid workspaceId,
                   String reportName, String filePath, ImportConflictHandlerModeEnum nameConflict, Int32 timeout)
                      at Microsoft.PowerBI.Commands.Reports.NewPowerBIReport.ExecuteCmdlet()
                      at Microsoft.PowerBI.Commands.Common.PowerBICmdlet.ProcessRecord()
```

Comment: Can you run "Resolve-PowerBIError -Last" and share with us the details?

Comment: I have added the results to Resolve-PowerBIError -Last

Comment: Does your service principal have build permissions on the dataset? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/service-datasets-build-permissions

Comment: I can remove a dataset using my service principle, in my code I cant work out how to even assign an existing dataset when no model exists